# I am getting null value in session when I am trying to pass value from one form to another

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using session to carry the value to another page in ASP.NET using C#, but the page I am redirecting to is getting null value. However, I tried passing value through session in simple application, and it's working well. Please help me out where am I going wrong?

```
// Login.aspx.cs
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("select Username, Password, Fname from Customer where Username = '" + txtCust.Text + "' and Password = '" + txtPass3.Text + "'",con);

rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (rd.Read())
{
    a = rd.GetValue(0).ToString();
    b = rd.GetValue(1).ToString();
    c = rd.GetValue(2).ToString();
}

con.Close();

if (a != txtCust.Text)
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Invalid Username')</script>");
else if (b != txtPass3.Text)
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Invalid Password')</script>");
else
{
    Session["user"] = c;
    Response.Redirect("Customer_Home.aspx");    
}

// Customer_Home.aspx.cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["user"] != null)
    {
        lblUser.Text = Session["user"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        lblUser.Text = "No value returned";
    }
}
```

I expect the output of the above code to be "Fname", but the actual output is "No value returned"

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Have you checked whether the debugger is getting into the else statement?

Comment: Also check rd.GetValue(2).ToString(); is null or not

Comment: @AA **yes the debugger is getting into else statement and rd.GetValue(2) is containing some value but its not carried to another page **

Comment: Hope you have checked  Session["user"] after assigning value into it.

Comment: @AA yes, i tried printing value by Response.Write(Session["user"]) and i am getting as expected.

Comment: Have you set any postback url anywhere? Also In Customer_Home.aspx.cs is it going to else part?

Comment: @AA No postback url is set. and Customer_Home is not redirected to any other page for now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to have no problem. But you can try using QueryString.

// Login.aspx.cs

Response.Redirect("Customer_Home.aspx?user=" + Server.UrlEncode(c);

// Customer_Home.aspx.cs

string value = Request.QueryString["user"].ToString();

Comment: using this i can only carry the value to next page, but how can i pass the values in multiple pages?